# Unable to update the record in a table

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Am using toggle button to enable and disable mail

If the toggle button is enabled then i used to update record in table

But i could not. Please help to resolve this. Am using rails 4.2.6 version

Am using javascript, inside that i am having erb code

Here is my code

```
<input class= "button" type="button" value="Enable mail" onclick="return change(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function change( el )
{
    if ( el.value === "Enable mail" )


    <%
            @changemail=User.find_by(role: 'TL')
            @changemail.update(mail: '1')
    %>

        el.value = "Disable mail";

   else
       <%
            @changemail=User.find_by(role: 'TL')
            @changemail.update(mail: '0')
       %> 
       el.value = "Enable mail";
}
</script>
```

Where,

```
User is my table
role and mail are columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside <% %> will be processed on server side and will do:

```
@changemail=User.find_by(role: 'TL')
@changemail.update(mail: '1')

@changemail=User.find_by(role: 'TL')
@changemail.update(mail: '0')
```

After that on  client side your function will look like below:

```
function change( el )
{
   if ( el.value === "Enable mail" )
       el.value = "Disable mail";
   else
       el.value = "Enable mail";
}
```

If you want to enable/disable mail on client side without reloading page use e.g Ajax.